# Referenced dll in web app project is not needed local but won't work unless copy to local is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a framework 4.5 (C#) web app project that is using another project (framework 4.0 C#) dll. The 4.0 project is deployed to the target server with an installshield routine. So in my 4.5 project I add the dll as a reference but I don't really want to use that dll. I want to use the one that is installed (in what I assume is the GAC) on the target server (so I can update 4.0 dll  project as needed). But my 4.5 web app doesn't work unless I use "copy to local" for the 4.0 DLL reference??? So it then sits in my BIN folder of my 4.5 web app.

The 4.0 project DLL does have a TLB file but that cannot be added to my 4.5 project, when trying I get

```
The "ActiveX type library ".." was not exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.
```

So I'm adding the 4.0 dll via browse and selecting the 4.0 dll.

The browse to dll is the same location and install (of the 4.0 project) on my dev machine as it installed on the target server.

Comment: Is your 4.0 dll really in GAC? `At run time, components must be either in the output path of the project or in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). If the project contains a reference to an object that is not in one of these locations, you must copy the reference to the output path of the project when you build the project.`

Comment: In the the GAC, it should be. Installshield routine to do so. But then agian I don't see it in C:\Windows\assembly. But I did install the same install package on my dev machine and select the DLL in that manner to add to the 4.5 project. Shouldn't that be enough to not be required to copy local (in bin folder)?

Comment: How you added reference? Browsed to \windows\assembly and selected dll? Or you selected dll from installation directory? You told that you cant see it in GAC, so it might be that installation extracts dll in installation dir, but not in GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing the 4.0 dll on your own machine, in the same way it is installed on the target server.  You then should no longer need to reference it.

Comment: Sorry, left out. I did do that. The same install was performed on my local machine. I then selected the DLL via the folder it was installed to (per the install information in original post).

Comment: Well, I checked my Installshield routine and I did not have the GAC set as the target location, I needed to set in folder structure for some really old tech that also uses that 4.0 DLL. So I moved over the GAC util (and it's fiels) since they are not deployed via the frameworks (why makes no sense what-so-ever)!. And then registered the same DLL in GAC, then I don't need to save local :)!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked my Installshield routine and I did not have the GAC set as the target location. Because I originally developed that 4.0 DLL for some really old technology requiring only COM and a local folder to save to. So instead of redoing my IS project I moved over the GAC util (and its files) since they are not deployed via the framework (i.e 4.0) (why makes no sense what-so-ever). And then registered the same DLL in GAC, then I don't need to (in VS2012) save resource to local.